# Pass an id of array and return what ids object node/express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, postman

Should I just request arrays of id then populate the id passes to my controller?

I have a controller that request only an id then return it on the field requested. Though I haven't tried to populate that id to return its value to object.

And if it passes array id, is there a way to check if i pass an array or not? Or just make a condition about it?

This is my router controller that should pass an array of id

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const GroupBand = require('../models/groupBand.models')
const Mongoose = require('mongoose')
const ObjectId = Mongoose.Types.ObjectId
// const Singer = require('../models/singer.models')

router.post("/addBand", async (req, res) => {
  const newBand = new GroupBand({
    bandName: req.body.bandName,
    singer: ObjectId(req.body.singer),
    debutDate: req.body.debutDate
  });

  try {
    const audio = await newBand.save();
    res.status(201).json(audio);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(400).json(err);
  }
```

How to accept arrays of id and populate id to return as arrays of object
I wanted it to return like this

```
bandName: 'Little Mix',
singer: [
 {
  _id: 1,
  name: 'Jesy'
 },
 {
  _id: 2,
  name: 'Perrie'
 },
 {
  _id: 3,
  name: 'Jade'
 },
 {
  _id: 4,
  name: 'Leigh-Anne'
 }
],
debutDate: '2011'
```

Comment: Please provide a **minimal working example** as example of what you have now and what you're trying to have as a result. The question is a bit unclear IMO

Comment: I just edited my question, I'm sorry for my short question provided